# Laravel: Trying to get property of non-object (relationship)

Tags: php, oop, laravel

I don't know why this isn't working. Every other relationship is working fine. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. This is the error: `Trying to get property of non-object`

This is my controller:

```
public function users()
{
    $userTheme = ThemeUser::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(20);
    return view('admin.users', compact('userTheme'));
}
```

This is my view:

```
@foreach($userTheme as $bought)

    <ul>
    <li>{{$bought->user->name}}</li>
    </ul>

@endforeach
```

This is my App/User:

```
public function themeUser()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\ThemeUser');
}
```

This is my App/ThemeUser

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Comment: Does every single theme user have a parent user? If not, it'll throw that error when it gets to a person without a user because you are trying to access the name of null / nobody.

Comment: Okay I get it now. Thanks

Comment: Where is the error being thrown

Answer (score 0):

Do the following, to check if the user is not null:

```
<?php 
    print_r($bought->user);
    die(); 
?>
```